# on my macbook air M1 the sound is not working in chrome

Tags: google-chrome

The problem is specific to one user and only occurs in chrome:

- using safari or another app e.g. zoom there is no problem
- logging in as another user there is no problem in chrome

Comment: Consider trying a Chrome alternative like Edge - this would confirm whether it's a Chrome specific issue or whether it affects all similar browsers (Edge and Chrome share a large percentage of their code)

Comment: I use already safari as alternative, that works fine although I had an issue with apple App Store version of lastpass, i had to revert to an older version of lastpass (4.6.0) to make it work in safari